# MVC 4 Flexigrid works fine in debug mode but does not show data when site is deployed

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, flexigrid

I've started trying to learn MVC 4 and having a rough go of it.  I've managed to get Flexigrid to work when displaying data from a database table when VS2010 is in debug mode but when I deploy the site my flexigrid does not show any records at all.  From what I can tell, it's not hitting the controller at all.  I've run out of ideas on how to fix this....

```
            $('#MySkillList').flexigrid({
        url: '/Home/ListMySkills',
        dataType: 'json',
        colModel: [
            {
            display: 'SkillName',
            name: 'SkillName',
            width: 180,
            sortable: true,
            align: 'left'
        },{
            display: 'SkillID',
            name: 'SkillID',
            width: 100,
            sortable: true,
            align: 'left',
        },{
            display: 'PersonID',
            name: 'PersonID',
            width: 100,
            sortable: true,
            align: 'left',
        },{
            display: 'Validated',
            name: 'Validated',
            width: 100,
            sortable: true,
            align: 'left'
        }],
        sortname: "SkillName",
        sortorder: "asc",
        usepager: true,
        title: 'My Skills',
        useRp: true,
        rp: 15,
        showTableToggleBtn: true,
        width: 600,
        height: 200
    });
```

controller

```
    public ActionResult ListMySkills(FreeLancererSkills fModel)
    {
        string GUID = LoginGuid;
        string SQL = "EXEC FreelancerSkills_Get '"+GUID+"'";

        DBLayer DBL = new DBLayer();
        DataSet DS = DBL.GetData(connString, SQL);

        List<FreeLancererSkills> iList = new List<FreeLancererSkills>();

        var model = new FreelancerSkillsCollection();
        int i = 1;

        foreach(DataRow DR in DS.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            FreeLancererSkills iSkills = new FreeLancererSkills();

            iSkills.LoginGuid = GUID;
            iSkills.PersonID = DR["PersonID"].ToString();
            iSkills.SkillID = DR["SkillID"].ToString();
            iSkills.SkillName = DR["SkillName"].ToString();
            iSkills.Validated = DR["Validated"].ToString();

            iList.Add(iSkills);

            i++;
        }


        TempData["LoginToken"] = GUID;
        return JsonResult(iList.ToList(), 1, i);
    }

    private JsonResult JsonReturn(List<FreeLancererSkills> items, int page, int total)
    {
        return Json(
                new
                {page, total, rows = items.Select(x => new
                           {
                                id = x.SkillID,
                                // either use GetPropertyList(x) method to get all columns 
                                cell = new object[] { x.SkillName, x.SkillID, x.PersonID, x.Validated }
                            })
                }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Hopefully someone will be able to help me figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Chrome , You can check if there is a http request for the resource `/Home/ListMySkills` in the `F12->Network tab`. please check it .

Another check point is using `firebug` to check if there is any error within the page where you load data.

Or you can debug the the method `populate` function in flexigrid.js to see what happen to you code.